# convert newline character to html tag in oracle sql 11g

Tags: expression, transformation, informatica

I am reading a file which has many descriptive fields of length 4000 bytes.
While reading this file as a table I could not put the conditions into the source qualifier because it does not have enough space to put SQL in it.

Hence i decided to put replace newline character by spaces in a expression transformation.

I tried the following code:

```
REPLACECHR(0,SUPSPD_COMMUNICATION_PLAN, CHR(10)||CHR(11)||CHR(12),'<br/>')
```

I am getting `<` in the output.

How do i do this?

Comment: i have another option as through Source qualifier.
 
Can i achieve the same logic ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide some examples. Also, what do you mean by 'While reading this files as table'? You cannot override SQL query in flat file source qualifier.

Comment: I >guess< you get the error as each time SQ gets a newline character, it treats this as a new row. You probably would need to do the replacement before reading the file with Informatica. Try sed or other command line tool you have available.

Comment: For Samik, while we import the file, we treat as ORacle source.In that way we can use that file as oracle source.

Comment: For Maciejg, i have hundred columns, out of 100 cols, we have ten descriptive columns. each column can hold 10 lines of information. So while we load this information in warehouse and finally it will displayed reporting tool.  Hence i want to add html tag for new line chaaracters.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Informatica but I assume that `REPLACECHR` is a mapping funtion mapping each character of the first string to the corresponding (position wise) character of the second string. So a `chr(10)` will be mapped onto `<`. What you actually need is a replacement function for substrings which you will have to call to replace `chr(10)` by `<br/>`.